# Euler angles and curvilinear coordinate systems

Tags: rotation, coordinate-systems

If I have a curvilinear coordinate system and supposing I impose the condition that back transformations to Cartesian coordinate system are not permitted. I perform a rotation of the three axes( say latitude, longitude and a proprietary vertical coordinate) to a rotated system (with new latitude , longitude and vertical coordinate) can we still use Euler angles to define these three rotations ? These three axes are non orthogonal to each other.